# Counterexample for fixed point theorems

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

There are many of fixed point theorems but two of them are:

**Krasnoselskii theorem:**

Let K be a non-empty, bounded, closed and convex subset of Banach space E. Moreover let $f: K \to E$ be a contraction and let $g: K \to E$ be a compact mapping and $f(x) + g(y) \in K$ for all $x,y \in K$. Then the mapping $F(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ has a fixed point.

**Darbo theorem**

Let assume that $f$ is continuous mapping of a non-empty closed, convex and bounded subset $K$ of a Banach space $E$ into inself and there exist constant $0 < k < 1$ such that
$$
\alpha(f(A)) \leq k \alpha(A)
$$
for every set $A \subset K$. Then the mapping $f$ possesses a fixed point. Where $\alpha$ is  Kuratowski measure of non-compactness.

It is easy to see that if $f$ satisfies assumptions of Krasnoselskii theorem, then also satisfies assumptions of Darbo theorem. Is there any counterexample of function that satisfies assumptions of Darbo theorem but not Krasnoselskii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "yes". In the following let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denote the Kuratowski and the Hausdorff measure of non-compactness, respectively. Note that
$$
\beta(A) \le \alpha(A) \le 2 \beta(A)
$$
for each bounded subset $A$ of a Banach space $E$. The following example is in $E:=c_0(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ (endowed with the maximum norm $\|\cdot\|$). In this space we have the following representation of $\beta$: For each bounded set $A \subseteq E$:
$$
\beta(A)= \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{x \in A} (\max \{|x_k|: k \ge n\})), 
$$
see Banas J., Goebel K. Measures of noncompactness in Banach spaces, 6.1.

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$
\varphi(t)=\frac{t}{4} \sin(1/t) ~ (t \not=0), \quad \varphi(0)=0,
$$
and note that $|\varphi(t)| \le |t|/4$.
Let $K$ denote the closed unit ball in $E$ and set $f:K \to K$ as
$$
f(x)=f((x_k)_{k=1}^\infty) :=(\varphi(x_k))_{k=1}^\infty.
$$
Now, for each set $A \subseteq K$ we have
$$
\beta(f(A)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{y \in f(A)} \max \{|y_k|: k \ge n\} 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in A} \max \{|\varphi(x_k)|: k \ge n\} \le \frac{1}{4} \beta(A),
$$
thus
$$
\alpha(f(A)) \le \frac{1}{2} \beta(A) \le \frac{1}{2}\alpha(A).
$$
Now we show that $f$ is not the sum of a contraction (even a Lipschitz map) and a compact map:
Assume by contradiction that there are functions $g, h:K \to E$ such that

1.) $\forall x \in K$: $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$,

2.) $\exists L \ge 0$ $\forall x,y \in K$: $\|g(x)-g(y)\| \le L\|x-y\|$,

3.) $\overline {h(K)}$ is compact.

Since the derivative of $\varphi$ is unbounded (in both directions) near $0$ we find $-1 \le \eta < \xi \le 1$ such that
$$
(\ast) \quad \varphi(\xi)-\varphi(\eta) >  L (\xi-\eta).
$$

For $m \in \mathbb{N}$ set $e^{(m)}:=(\delta_{k,m})=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$, and
$$
x^{(m)}:= \xi e^{(m)}, ~~ y^{(m)}:= \eta e^{(m)}, ~~ u^{(m)}:= g(x^{(m)})-g(y^{(m)}), ~~ v^{(m)}:= h(x^{(m)})-h(y^{(m)})
$$
(note that $x^{(m)},y^{(m)} \in K$).

By 1.) and 2.) we have for each $m$:
$$
(\ast\ast) ~~ \varphi(\xi)-\varphi(\eta)=u^{(m)}_m + v^{(m)}_m \le L\|x^{(m)}-y^{(m)}\| + v^{(m)}_m = L(\xi-\eta)+ v^{(m)}_m.
$$
Next, by 3.), the sequence $(v^{(m)})$ has a convergent subsequence $(v^{(m_j)})$ with limit $w=(w_k) \in E$, say. We have
$$
|v^{(m_j)}_{m_j}| \le |v^{(m_j)}_{m_j}-w_{m_j}| + |w_{m_j}|\le \|v^{(m_j)}-w\| + |w_{m_j}| \to 0 \quad (j \to \infty).
$$
Now $(\ast\ast)$ with $m=m_j$ and $j \to \infty$ yields $\varphi(\xi)-\varphi(\eta) \le  L (\xi-\eta)$,
a contradiction to $(\ast)$.

Hope everything is correct, please check.

Comment: Seems fine to me, don't see any mistakes. Thank you a lot, such a elegant counterexample